# How can I optimize correlated mysql subquery? In laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have 2 tables in Laravel project

1) cars(id, token, name)

2) tracking( id, car_id , lat, lng, point_time)

The tracking table contains all GSP data of the car and contains huge data!

I need to get last tracking data of each car.

```
SELECT distinct `a`.`id` ,
                ( SELECT MAX(`tracking`.`point_time`)
                FROM `tracking`
                WHERE tracking.car_id = a.id ) as `last_time`
FROM `cars` AS `a`
```

For now, this query works fine but takes about 4 seconds to execute!

I need a replacement query to run faster.

I prefer to execute a raw sql query to perform faster as you see above.

Comment: Why not try with JOIN.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn your subquery(`O(n^2)`) into a join like this:

```
select c.id,
    t.`last_time`
from `cars` c
left outer join (
    select car_id,
        MAX(t.`point_time`) `last_time`
    from `tracking` t
    group by car_id
    ) t on c.id = t.car_id;
```

Comment: This is the right answer, and much faster than SELECT ... DISTINCT. I'd just point out that since you're only getting one result per car, you'd be better with an INNER join unless you expect a null result.

Comment: No. I'd want `null` in case there is no record in the `tracking` table.

Comment: Sure. But to me this resembles e.g. the leaderboard for a videogame. So using only INNER JOIN and LIMIT 10 on the inner query would be a lot faster if you don't need to show any null results.

Answer (score 0):

I do not think `MAX` and `GROUP BY` is that great, just using `order by`, also you should add `index` on *last_time*, try this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT r.*
FROM 
( 
    SELECT c.id, t.last_time
    FROM cars AS c 
    LEFT JOIN tracking as t
    ON t.car_id = c.id
    ORDER BY c.id, t.last_time DESC
) AS r
```